# Save as Macro Enabled Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in a .xlsm file.

```
Sub SaveReport()

Dim ReportName As String
    ReportName = Sheets("Report").Range("B2")

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show ReportName

End Sub
```

How can I make it save as a Macro Enabled file format by default?

Comment: See the [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas#main) docs; specify the *FileFormat*? Note that you could also use [`Application.GetSaveAsFilename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some different versions of saving it as ".xlsm"

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveReport_1()

Dim ReportName As String
    ReportName = Sheets("Report").Range("B2")
    Application.DefaultSaveFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show ReportName

End Sub



Sub SaveReport_2()

Dim ReportName As String
    ReportName = Sheets("Report").Range("B2")

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show ReportName, 52
End Sub



Sub SaveReport_3()

Dim ReportName As String
    ReportName = Sheets("Report").Range("B2")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Application.GetSaveAsFilename(ReportName, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", , "Save As xlsm file")
End Sub
```

Comment: these are great examples. they all work. thank you.

Comment: Glad to help :), happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit ' It is a good practice to use this to force the compiler to ask for
                ' Var declaration before use it

Sub SaveReport()
    Dim ReportName As String 'As I told you you need to declare every var before
    Dim T As Workbook: Set T = ThisWorkbook 'Store the Workbook inside the var
                                            'Notice you can use "Thisworkbook" as a Var

    ReportName = Sheets("Report").Range("B2")
    T.SaveAs Filename:=ReportName, FileFormat:=52 'use this statement to:
                                                  ' Save the workbook WITHOUT any dialog box
                                                  ' and define the format you want
    'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show ReportName 
    'This line is not necesary.
End Sub
```

Here some links to know how it works in detail:

[Workbook.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

[XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)